# Request Comment on Behalf not working with zendesk API

Tags: node.js, zendesk, zendesk-api

I'm making a Node application that uses Zendesk API. Users logged in and can create tickets through my application.

To create tickets, I use this configuration

```
var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'url/api/v2/requests.json',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer adminToken',
      'X-On-Behalf-Of': 'emailOfUser',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: ticket
  };  
axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
    //My code
    })
```

With `X-On-Behalf-Of` I can create tickets for the user logged in with my admin token.

However, it doesn't work for updating the ticket with comments. I got a `Forbidden error`. Here is my code :

```
var config = {
    method: 'put',
    url: 'url/api/v2/requests/' + idTicket,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer adminToken',
      'X-On-Behalf-Of': 'emailOfUser',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: { "request": { "comment": { "body": message, "public": true, "author_id": userId } } }
  };
```

And when I remove the `X-On-Behalf-Of`, the comment is publish, but with my name, the admin name, and not the user name.

Do you know a solution for that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your token is missing `impersonate` scope.

Example for authorization code grant:
`https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/oauth/authorizations/new?client_id=foo&redirect_uri=bar&scope=impersonate+write&response_type=code`